# Are Ruby fork are COW friendly if yes how to test it

Tags: ruby, copy-on-write

I have read some where that ruby **fork** are **COW** friendly
ok here the [link](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2007/04/05/saving-memory-in-ruby-on-rails//)

But then when I happen to google around for more info on it I found out that Ruby does not support **COW** (copy on write)

Now I'm actually a bit confuse whether ruby actually support or not **COW** functionality

I'm also aware that **REE** and **Rubinius** has a **COW friendly GC** so 
does that me REE and Rubinius support **COW** functionality

I yes I'm dying to test it , can anyone suggest me that if ruby support **COW** functionality then how to **write a sample** code to test **COW concept in Ruby**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork` being copy-on-write is a property of your operating system kernel, not Ruby. On most UNIX-like systems, it is.

On Linux, for example, you can look in `/proc/pid/smaps` and look for how much of the heap mapping is shared. Here is an example from `bash` doing a fork:

```
02020000-023cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
Size:               3764 kB
Rss:                3716 kB
Pss:                1282 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:       3652 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:        64 kB
Referenced:          144 kB
Anonymous:          3716 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
```

So, out of its 3764k heap, 3652k is shared. See [proc.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) for documentation on the files in `/proc`.

Of course, Ruby may have something that causes the COW pages to be copied (e.g., maybe its garbage collector writes to each page), but you'll be able to see that by the shared count going to 0.

Comment: Yes, GC is the issue.  Some versions of Ruby have GC behavior that causes a forked Ruby to do extraneous copies, some (e.g. Ruby Enterprise Edition) don't.

Comment: @derobert, I understand COW is property of OS but all I wanted from that Question whether ruby inherit that propery when it actually do a fork(i yes then how to test it using ruby program) and as mention in Q I was confuse on that regards not whether my OS support COW or not which I'm aware it does .

Comment: @Viren Ruby (or anything else) doing a fork calls `fork`. If the OS uses COW, it gets COW. Checking if the pages *stay* shared is OS-specific; which OS are you trying to check on? I showed Linux as an example.

Comment: @derobert How would you do it in OS X? using top? I can see kshrd and rshrd columns, is that it?

Comment: @Agis I don't know how to check on OS X. You could probably ask a question on that... here, at Unix.SE, or maybe at Ask Different.